# Remake of this "contact form" to send out emails (Ajax)

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have followed this tutorial, and made everything like the tutorial says... When I click submit it says "this wont actually send out emails".

Here is the [tutorial](http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial182_How-to-create-an-AJAX-contact-form.html)

So my Q is this, would it be too hard to "actually send out emails" with this?
How can I implement it into this?

Thanks

PS: No JQuery please...

Comment: Simply put, you would need an SMTP to send the e-mail.

Comment: Well, don't I need any code for that? in addition that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest method would be to use the PHP [`mail()`](http://php.net/mail) function. Simply plug this into the top of process.php, utilising your form data.

**However** this will not take into account anything like form validation, spam filtering, abuse throttling, etc. Also, `mail()` does not work on every server - if this is the case for you, you will need to look into more advanced options like PHP SMTP libraries.

Comment: Thanks... But still, what I am after is the page NOT reloading... I will handle the validations before submitting. Thanks

Comment: My answer still stands though - mail() would run when process.php is called by your AJAX script, sending the email as you want.